How do you combine two json map files?
I am looking to map data across local authorities in the UK, but the only json files of LAs I have been able to find are of GB only (England, Scotland, Wales), whereas I want to include data for Northern Ireland's local government districts too. I have been able to find a json file for NI LGDs. Is there a way I can combine the two json files - GB LAs and NI LGDs into one? I would want the LAs and LGDs to be considered at the same level in this file, so sharing a code. It should be noted that I am not very experienced with code, so was hoping for a solution that can be executed within a text editor.
Alternatively if anyone knows of a freely available json or geojson file that already combines local authorities/gov districts of England, Wales, Scotland and NI, that would great!
